# How to submit form and have data stay in input field? Using AJAX and nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, ajax

I am trying to create a user settings page where a user inputs his/her information, clicks "save", then the page saves the data without clearing the inputted fields or reloading the page. The best example I can think of is the user account settings page on Udemy.

A LOT of the similar questions I've looked at are using `php` or renders data in a `div` below the `form`. I want the data to remain IN the `form inputs`. I'm using `nodejs`, `express`, `bodyparser`.

```
<form id="updateAccSettings" action="/account" method="POST">       
    <div class="form-group">
         <label for="address">Address* </label>
         <input class="form-control" type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address" required/>
    </div> 

    <div class="form-group">
         <label for="address2">Address 2 </label>
         <input class="form-control" type="text" name="address2" placeholder=""/>
    </div> 

    <div class="form-group">
         <label for="city">City* </label>
         <input class="form-control" type="text" name="city" placeholder="City" />
    </div> 

    <div class="form-group">
         <input type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Save"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

I've tried this with AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#updateAccSettings").on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var details = $("#updateAccSettings").serialize();
        $.post("/account", details, function(data){
            $("#updateAccSettings").html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

and this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#updateAccSettings").bind("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/account",
            data: $("#updateAccSettings").serialize(),
            success: function(){
                alert("You've successfully updated your account settings.")
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And I have this for my app.js

```
app.post("/account", function(req, res) {
    var address = req.body.address;
    var address2 = req.body.address2;
    var city = req.body.city;
    var updateAccount = {address: address, address2: address2, city: city};
    account.push(updateAccount);
    console.log("Updated data");
    res.redirect("/settings/account");
});
```

When I clicked `save`, I get a `Cannot read property of 'push' undefined`. I tried deleting the `var address`, `var address2`, etc and keeping only the `console.log` which logs whenever I click save but doesn't keep the data in the input. I tried adding `onsubmit="return false"` as an attribute on the `form` tag but the `console.log` doesn't run when I click save so I assume it's not doing anything with the data.

Not sure how to proceed from here. All my other forms use modals or render results in another page.

Comment: There are no errors in your HTML/JS but in the backend code you're trying to add data to `account` which is undefined. Where is this variable coming from?

Comment: How about giving the input fields ids and inserting their values again after the form has successfully submitted e.g give the first field id="address" and then in the ajax callback $("#address").val(data.address); (Sorry I don't know much about node.js. so im not sure if this is exactly right)

Comment: @Mimo I haven't gotten around to moving my data to a database yet. So I just defined a var account but haven't assigned it to anything. Does this mean once I set up a database using mongoose schema then the data will show in the inputted fields?

Comment: @TJS13 In this case just set up a dummy variable that rappresent the DB. You'll get rid of it once you have mongo up and running.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because you're trying to push onto an undefined variable. Namely in the last section when posted this app.post:

```
app.post("/account", function(req, res) {
    var address = req.body.address;
    var address2 = req.body.address2;
    var city = req.body.city;
    var updateAccount = {address: address, address2: address2, city: city};
    account.push(updateAccount); // error is being thrown here
    console.log("Updated data");
    res.redirect("/settings/account");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a dummy variable for account, you can send back to the frontend a json response to be read in the form success handler.
Example code: (I haven't tested it)
Backend:

```
app.post("/account", function(req, res) {
    var account = [];
    var address = req.body.address;
    var address2 = req.body.address2;
    var city = req.body.city;
    var updateAccount = { address, address2, city };
    account.push(updateAccount); // error is being thrown here
    console.log("Updated data");
    res.json(updateAccount);
});
```

Frontend:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#updateAccSettings").bind("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/account",
            data: $("#updateAccSettings").serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                $('#address').value(data.address);
                $('#address2').value(data.address2); 
                $('#city').value(data.city);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Mimo, I assigned the `var account` to an empty array, then tested this out and it shows `{"address":"123 Street Road","address2":"","city":""}` on a blank page. Same as Sarah's code up top. How could I get it to display in the form?

Comment: @TJS13 have you changed this line `res.json(updateAccount);` into your nodejs code? It is showing the json because you're redirecting somewhere or not stopping the form submission correctly.

Comment: Yes, I did. I double checked my code and it matches yours. The only thing that's different is I defined my `var account = [ ];` outside of the app.post. But even if I were to move it inside the app.post it's still showing the same output as my earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could give each of your form input fields an id (e.g the same as their "name" property)and get their values individually when doing the ajax request as follows (that way you can reinsert the values after the form is submitted):

## HTML

```
  <form id="updateAccSettings" action="" method="POST">       
        <div class="form-group">
             <label for="address">Address* </label>
             <input class="form-control" type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Address" required/>
        </div> 

        <div class="form-group">
             <label for="address2">Address 2 </label>
             <input class="form-control" type="text" name="address2" id="address2" placeholder=""/>
        </div> 

        <div class="form-group">
             <label for="city">City* </label>
             <input class="form-control" type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="City" />
        </div> 

        <div class="form-group">
             <input type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Save"/>
        </div>
    </form>
```

## JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#updateAccSettings").on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        //get the values of our input fields and store them in local variables
        var address = $("#address").val();
        var address2 = $("#address2").val();
        var city = $("#city").val();

        //prepare the data object to send in the ajax request
        var params = {"address": address, "address2": address2, "city" : city};
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/account",
            data: JSON.stringify(params),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                //the ajax request was successful
                //We can do something with the data we get back here.
                //Also we can reinsert the values (that were submitted) to the form
                $("#address").val(address);
                $("#address2").val(address2);
                $("#city").val(city);     
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                //an error occured in the request so handle it here
            }

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Now I don't get an error but it doesn't reinsert the values to the form. Instead it shows a blank page with this example object `{"address":"123 Street Road","address2":"","city":""}`

Comment: I'm not sure why that is happening. But if you are testing my code can you remove the line (in the ajax request) dataType: "json", (sometimes this causes problems if the server has not got the right headers).

Comment: Commented it out but same results :(

Comment: I think the problem os to do with your node js. @mimo is right that u should declare account as an array before using .push () on it. So add var account =[]; but also instead of res.redirect can u try res.send (updateAccount);

Comment: @TJS13 Hey I was just wondering is your app purely an express app? Or do you have a HTML/Javscript based client side app which makes API requests to your nodejs server side app? I have something working for you but my setup with the code is I have a html page called settings.html (where the form is) and then I have a separate express app that contains a REST API for me to make the ajax request to from the settings.html page.If the request is successful, then data is sent from the nodejs server side back to the settings.html page.This works perfect but I don't know if the setup is the same as u

Comment: Hi @Sarah. I use ejs/javascript. So I have an account.ejs file (where the form is), a script tag in the account.ejs file where I put in the ajax for now, and an app.js where I have REST set up. Not sure if this answers your question.

Comment: @TJS13 I see. That's different to my setup. Sorry nodejs is not really my area of expertise. I hope you find an answer. :)